# How to prevent duplicate code in Exception

Tags: java, exception, code-duplication

I have dozens of entities . And everytime I have to catch exceptions. Now I always have dupliate code. In this example all the catch blocks will be duplicate. How could I prevent this.

```
try {
        return someRepository.save(someEntity);
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
        throw new DuplicateEntityException(ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause());
    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
        throw new BusinessException(ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why throw own exceptions if you don't add additional logic?

Comment: I don't see any duplicates, the two catch clauses behave differently. Or do you have the entire block duplicated all over the place?

Comment: If you have the same code in multiple locations, you can write a `handleException(Exception e)` method that does instance checks and throws appropriate other exceptions.

Comment: Do the exception inherit from one another?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of below two approaches:

1) You can take help of Java generics. Create an generic method of type `someRepository.save(someEntity)`, which can accept any type of entity and put try catch around that method only. Like below: (Assuming return type is same, you can change also)

```
class BaseBean<T> { 
    public T save(T someEntity) {
        try {
            return someRepository.save(someEntity);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
            throw new DuplicateEntityException(ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause());
        } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
            throw new BusinessException(ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause());
        }
    }
}
```

2) You can use AOP (aspect oriented programming), where all the methods those are saving entity, wrap them with `around` aspect and catch them in the Aspect method. So it will be at single place. Like below : (If you don't want to catch the exception in complete method execution first approach is preferred)

```
@Aspect
public class ExceptionHandlerAspect {

  /**
   * @param pjp
   * @return
   * @throws Throwable
   */
  @Around("execution(public * package.name.*.*(..)) " + "&& within(*..*ClassEndingWith)"
      + "&& !execution(* package.name.of.aspect.class.*.*(..))")
  public Object translateToDataAccessException(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    try {
      return pjp.proceed();
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
        throw new DuplicateEntityException(ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause());
    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
        throw new BusinessException(ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause());
    }
  }
}
```